# identity based cryptography (IBE) without key escrow

Tags: identity-based-encryption, pki

I am trying to find a method of implementing identity based cryptography to generate key pairs without the use of a trusted PKG that holds the private keys. Has there been any solutions to overcoming this challenge?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to completely get rid of the PKG, but one can limit the amount of trust on a (single) PKG through distributed key generation --- see [BF01,§6](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/bfibe.pdf). On the other hand, one could hold the PKG accountable in case it behaves malicously --- see [Goy07](http://eprint.iacr.org/2007/368).

Comment: I guess your first link should point here: https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/bfibe.pdf